# Separate badge awarding systems?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does meta reputation and badges work?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/how-does-meta-reputation-and-badges-work)

I know that the reputation are equal on both main and meta sites. But why do meta and main sites use separate systems for awarding badges?

Please explain.

Comment: Have a look at http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/how-does-meta-reputation-and-badges-work

Comment: @Flow Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I think the MSO link in the other answer answers this most directly -- rep carries over so that users engaged in the main site have corresponding status when talking about the site on Meta.  Badges, on the other hand, are more commonly related to specific posts or actions and make more sense being separate for each site.